# push data from table rows into extern file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table **Tab** with a lots of columns and rows.

All columns name are stored in nvarchar variable separated with comma, sth like

```
set @col_names = 'col_a,col_b,col_c'
```

And now i want to push all rows from this table to external file.
To do this i use

```
set @cmd = 'echo '+' some text >>'+ @my_file_path;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

The problem i have is: how to store rows content in **@cmd** variable like:

```
val_a,val_b,val_c
```

So for example: if **Tab** content is:

```
col_a | col_b | col_c
------+-------+-------
 1a   |  1b   |  1c
 2a   |  2b   |  2c
 3a   |  3b   |  3c
```

i want inside my extern file text:

```
 (1a,1b,1c),
 (2a,2b,2c),
 (3a,3b,3c),
```

Finally my extern file should be executable sql code..

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but perhaps this will help

**Example**

```
Declare @col_name varchar(max) = 'col_a,col_b,col_c'
Declare @data     varchar(max) 

Create Table #Temp (X varchar(max))

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Insert Into #Temp
Select stuff(replace((Select concat('','',char(13),''('','+replace(@col_name,',',','','',')+','')'') 
                       From  Tab 
                       For XML Path ('''')),''&#x0D;'',char(13)),1,2,'''')
'
Exec(@SQL)

Select @data = X from #Temp
```

**Returns a string with chr(13) ... optional**

```
(1a,1b,1c),
(2a,2b,2c),
(3a,3b,3c)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server , the only utility to export data programmatically is **[bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)**.

An alternative (which I use everyday), is to create a [Sql Server Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bbdd51b2-a9b4-4916-ba6f-7957ac6c3f33). You can create a CLR stored procedure which receives 2 parameters:

- a query command and
- a output string.

In fact, I have CLR stored procedures for write data to a files, attach them in mail, or send them by FTP, call web services, etc. For all the missing functionality in Transact SQL :(